# Importing an NX Vite-React made npm library returns (Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have nx vite-react npm library that returns a component.

When running dev or building then vite preview everything works fine.

But when I published my npm library and tried to import it it gives a react is not defined error.

If import react like:

```
import React from 'react'
```

It would work but I want to remove the necessity on importing react on my code.

Here is my vite config:

```
  import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
    import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
    
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [react()],
    });

    {
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "**/*.js"]
}
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.lib.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ]
}
```